# Trying to add icon to tool-bar crashes OpenOffice Writer

Tags: crash, icons, toolbar, openoffice.org, openoffice-writer

I added *insert horizontal line* to **OpenOffice Writer 3.3.0 tool-bar**.
It was added as text - without an icon, viz:

[image: how the horizontal bar looks on the tool-bar]

I want to change the text to an icon, but when I go to the *change tool-bar* drop-down

[image]

*OpenOffice Writer crashes!*

[image]

## Can you suggest a way to *fix this issue*, or get its *root-cause*?

*OpenOffice Writer 3.3.0 - about data:*
[image: OpenOffice Writer 3.3.0 - about data]

Answer (score 0):

Such crashes normally occur with corrupt data in OOo's user directory.

Read in the community forum: [how to reset user profile](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=12426)

**Warning**: this will reset the installation to default, e.g. all your customizations are gone.